# Criar um único arquivo .jar com todos as Dependência no Netbeans

Tags: netbeans

Quando um projeto é compilado no Netbeans, são inclusos na pasta dist as bibliotecas, na pasta 'lib'.
Na Eclipse existe a possibilidade de criar um único arquivo jar com todos os arquivos inclusos.
Existe algo similar no Netbeans para facilitar a portabilidade?

grato

Comment: Tem que configurar no build.xml do maven algumas diretivas.

Comment: Se for jar, se tiver adicionado no projeto, não precisa fazer mais nada adicional.

Comment: Encontrei um bom link aqui... mas não posso responder.
http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/java/generating-executable-jar-file-with-all-dependencies-and-libraries-in-single-jar-using-netbeans-and-eclipse/

Comment: Recomendo usar o Maven para gerenciar dependências e também gerar o executável. Se interessar, posso ir atrás de uma resposta completa